# What's wrong with this proof that $\lim_{n \to\infty} a_{2n} = L$ implies $\lim_{n \to\infty} a_n = L$

Tags: real-analysis

What step in this "proof" that $\lim_{n \to\infty} a_{2n} = L$ implies $\lim_{n \to\infty} a_n = L$ is wrong:

1) $\lim_{n \to\infty} a_{2n} = L$

2) $\Rightarrow \forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists N \in\mathbb{N} \ni$ if $n \ge N$ then $|a_{2n} - L| < \epsilon$

3) let $k = 2n$ $\wedge$ $n \ge N$ $\iff$ $n = k/2 \ge N$ $\iff$ $k \ge 2N$

4) $\Rightarrow$ $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists N' \in\mathbb{N} \ni$ if $k \ge N'$ then $|a_k -L| < \epsilon$ where $N' = 2N$

5) $\Rightarrow$ $\lim_{k \to\infty} a_k = L$

The theorem is obviously wrong, just take $a_n = (-1)^n$ as a counterexample.

[Update]

To be precise, I'm only interested in what step in the above "proof" is wrong, not why the above "theorem" is wrong in general.

[Update]

Some people have had issues with my definition of the limit, specifically the "if $n \ge N$" clause. I got this straight from "Foundations of Mathematical Analysis" by Johnsonbaugh and Pfaffenberger (a Stanford University textbook):

$\lim_{n \to\infty} a_n = L$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists N \in \mathbb{N} \ni$ if $n \ge N$ then $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$

Note, some have taken issue with the fact that I've substituted quantifiers for some wording from text in the above definition, so here is the *exact* definition from the text:

$\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ has *limit* $L \in \mathbb{R}$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a positive integer $N$, such that if $n \ge N$, then $|a_n -L| < \epsilon$

Comment: The sequence $a_k$ is not the original sequence $a_n$ if $k = 2n$.

Comment: $k = 2n$ - you proved what you started from.

Comment: All the following terms after $a_{k}$ needs also to be within this interval. Or take $a_{k+1}$, you can't divide it by two since your $k$ is even, so you don't have a proof, since a following term in your sequence doesn't follow the rule of the limit. Your limit definition is wrong, it is \forall{n} \get

Comment: the fact is that $\lim_{n \to\infty} a_{2n} = L$ can't give any information on the behavour of $a_k$ when $k$ is odd

Comment: You did not justify your writing of "$\Rightarrow$"

Comment: @JeanRostan the definition of the limit is correct, see Foundations of Mathematical Analysis by Johnsonbauh and Pfaffenberger.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen can you elaborate, thanks.

Comment: Steps 4 and 5 are assertions for all integer $k$ where step 3 assumes $k=2n$ is an even integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can note that $n$ is a positive integer and hence $k=2n$ implies that $k$ is an even positive integer. Your final statement $(4)$ thus deals with all even $k>N'$ and not all $k$ as required by definition of limit.

Comment: Thanks, that's the crux of the problem. To symbolizes it, in step 4) I implicitly say $...\forall k[k \in \mathbb{2N} \wedge k \ge N' => |a_k -L| < \epsilon]...$ but the definition of the limit requires $...\forall k[k \in \mathbb{N} \wedge k \ge N' => |a_k -L| < \epsilon]...$ and you can't get the latter from the former.

Comment: @ArnautB: forget my last deleted comment. I am glad you understood the issue here.

Comment: @ArnautB: just to confirm your symbolic interpretation is exactly same as in my answer and what you have wrote in your comment is the correct argument.

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies in your definition of a limit:

$$ \forall \epsilon >0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n\geq N, |a_n-L|<\epsilon $$.

The second $\forall$ is key.

See your mistake?

Comment: Bill.Exactly, +1.

Comment: Are you saying my definition of the limit is incorrect?

Comment: I think your definition is quite ambiguous and it is that ambiguity that lead you to this mistake: "if $n \geq N$" does not denote a set but rather a property where $n$ would have been introduced beforehand.

Comment: As I noted elsewhere this definition is right out of Foundations of Mathematical Analysis by Johnsonbaugh and Pfaffenberger, a textbook used in Stanford. Sorry, I fail to see the ambiguity, can you elaborate? $n$ is implictly a natural number since $a_n$ is a sequence.

Comment: @JeanRostan Sorry I don't read it that way, and since I got this definition straight from a Stanford University textbook I think I stand on solid ground.

Comment: @ArnautB then it is my misunderstanding of your definition. However, the point stands, all subsequent terms of the sequence must be within this interval. Or in your case, only odd indexed terms are within, you have no proof for the other terms.

Comment: @JeanRostan I see that and I think I indicated I saw that with my counterexample. What I fail to see is what step in the "proof" goes wrong. I understand why the "theorem" is wrong, what I don't get is, following the steps in the "proof", which step leaves me awry. BillOHaran answer indicates why the theorem is wrong, but doesn't answer my question of "what step in the proof is wrong". I'll edit my original post to make this more clear.

Comment: @ArnautB the wrong step is  n=k/2≥N ⟺ k≥2N because you can divide by 2 only for odd indexes, by using the $2$ on the other side, you lose the equivalence, which results in the rest of the assumptions not equivalent. So you choose a specific $n$, which is odd. Or the $\forall$ forbids you from choosing a specific $n$, you must consider all of them $\geq N$

Comment: Having looked at your reference, I also stand my ground. The definition you gave is **not** the one stated in the book because, they make use of the English language without any quantifiers ($\forall$ , $\exists$). What you gave mixed quantifiers and English which often leads to such confusions. In English, as I stated earlier, the *if* statement may mean $\forall$ or introduce the first clause of an implication. Also, as a side note, your reference being used in Stanford is no guarantee of quality as far as I'm concerned. However this site is not the place to discuss that.

Comment: @BillO'Haran I will edit my post to include the exact definition they give in the book. I highly disagree that in English the $if$ statement may mean $\forall$, please provide reference. To my knowledge this text is used in three universities, and neither on the class websites nor on the author's errata webpage is there any indication that the definition in question is incorrect.

Comment: @BillO'Haran Mixed quantifiers and English does not lead to such confusions, it's standard practice in every upper division math class I've had. Quantifiers are symbols just like any other symbols.

Comment: Again, a book being used somewhere is no argument. I never said the definition given in the book was incorrect, having looked at it, it is actually perfectly equivalent to the one I gave. I'll be honest with you: I do not have any reference to provide. However, I would like you to understand that the whole problem you have comes down to translating that *if* correctly. Since you seem a little protective of what you think, remember that you (rightfully) accepted that your proof is wrong, so accept that there is something wrong with your proof ;)

Comment: In the particular case of limits, have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Formal_definition).

Comment: @ArnautB your last edit means we do have the same definition, one using English words, and the other quantifier. Do note that there's no existence in front of the $n$ in the definition, so it's interpreted as a $\forall$ and we get to the same definition (not the one you initially wrote). The key point is $n$ is only defined by $\geq N$ which means all natural integers greater than this $N$. Or in your case, you can only find greater **even** integers, not all integers, is that clear ?

Answer (score 1):

Your highly abbreviated language hides the misstatement.

It is *incorrect* to say that "$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{2n}=L$" implies that "if $n \geq N$ then $|a_{2n}-L|<\epsilon$".

Rather, the correct conclusion is that "if $n$ is an **integer** with $n \geq N$ then $|a_{2n}-L|<\epsilon$".

This is implicit when using sequences, but it must be considered nonetheless.

Comment: The textbook Foundations of Mathematical Analysis by Johnsonbaugh and Pfaffenberger states it like that. This is a textbook used in Stanford. As you say it is implicit $n$ is an integer since we're using sequences, therefore I don't think the wording is incorrect.

Comment: @ArnautB : I don’t mean to say your wording is incorrect—it is perfectly acceptable. I just mean you have to be careful to only use expressions which represent integers for subscripts. I think that’s what got glossed over in the proof.